# VBA: Run-time error 424: Object required when trying to web scrape

Tags: vba, object

I'm trying to update various fund sizes using morgninstar.co.uk. The code worked fine until it suddenly stopped and gave an error:
"Run-time error 424: Object required". 
The exact line where the error occurs is:

`Set allData = IE.document.getElementById("overviewQuickstatsDiv").getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)`

The idea is to ultimately scan the whole "tbody"-tag and look for the line "Fund Size" inside "tr" and "td"-tags. When "Fund Size" is found, the code would return the 3rd "td"-tag (actual fund size).
After this I'd add a loop to loop through a list of funds that I've got.
As the code stopped working completely, I haven't got this far yet. Here I'm just trying to check if the code returns the actual fund size.
Since there are not always 3 "td"-tags inside the "tr"-tags, I'll still have to construct some sort of IF-statement to fix that issue.

But for now I'd just want to know how I could get the code running again? I've spent great deal of time searching for an answer but as it seems that this is a variable type problem the solution depends on the situation.

I'm using Excel 2010 and Internet Explorer 11.

URL in easy form to copy-paste:
http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW

```
Sub testToScrapeWholeTbodyTag()

'Microsoft Internet Controls
'Microsoft HTML Object Library
'Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation


'======Opens URL======
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With IE
    .navigate "http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW"
    .Visible = False
End With

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend


'======Got from internet, fixed a previous error. However, I'm not 100% sure what this does======
Dim sh
Dim eachIE As Object

Do
    Set sh = New Shell32.Shell
    For Each eachIE In sh.Windows
        If InStr(1, eachIE.LocationURL, "http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW") Then
            Set IE = eachIE
            IE.Visible = False  '"This is here because in some environments, the new process defaults to Visible."
            Exit Do
            End If
        Next eachIE
    Loop
Set eachIE = Nothing
Set sh = Nothing





'======Looks for the "Fund Size"======
'Trying to look for "Fund Size" inside "tr"-tag and if found, return the value in the 3rd "tr"-tag
Set allData = IE.document.getElementById("overviewQuickstatsDiv").getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0) 'Run-time error 424: Object required
row1 = allData.getElementsByTagName("tr")(5).Cells(0).innerHTML
row2 = allData.getElementsByTagName("tr")(5).Cells(1).innerHTML
row3 = allData.getElementsByTagName("tr")(5).Cells(2).innerHTML

    If Left(row1, 9) = "Fund Size" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3") = Split(row3, ";")(1)
    End If

Debug.Print allData.getElementsByTagName("tr")(5).Cells(0).innerHTML '"Fund Size"
Debug.Print allData.getElementsByTagName("tr")(5).Cells(2).innerHTML 'Actual fund size


IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing


End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
Switched method. Now the problem is to get the fund size extracted. So the below code works as it is but I'd need to add a couple of lines to get the fund size out of it. This is my first time using this method so it may well be that I've just not understood some really basic thing. Still, I wasn't able to find a solution to this on my own.

```
Sub XMLhttpRequestTest()

'Microsoft XML, v 6.0
'Microsoft HTML object library

Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim ohttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 

Dim myurl As String
Dim TRelements As Object
Dim TRelement As Object

myurl = "http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW"
ohttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
ohttp.send


HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = ohttp.responseText

With HTMLDoc.body
    Set TRelements = .getElementsByTagName("tr")

    For Each TRelement In TRelements
        Debug.Print TRelement.innerText
    Next

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: No repro. Your code runs just fine at my end.

Comment: Why is this tagged as [required]?  Tag description is "Required is an HTML attribute of an input element that forces that the input be supplied." so do you believe that the error is related somehow to the use of that attribute???

Comment: `IE`has not finished loading I guess, check the value `IE.Document.Body`. Use `While `IE.busy OR IE.Readystate <> 4` after navigate. Skip the do loop, you already have the correct `IE`at beginning and this loop can get infinite if `Instr`condition don't get true.

Comment: Very simple: the div you select does not contain a `tbody`element, hence `.getElementsByTagName("tbody")` returns NULL.

Comment: The code worked once again for a while until it stopped. I did further research and the reason might be related to use of Internet Explorer. The code might try to open "too many" windows (or something like that) which causes the code to somehow stop. Currently I get an error on the 2nd line (Set IE = ...). Error msg: "vba run time error'-2147467259 (80004005)': automation error unspesified error". I switched to XML HttpRequest method and it seems to work. I only have problems with parsing the data. I added the code above as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) of

```
#overviewQuickstatsDiv td.line.text
```

And then select the element at index 4

`#` means id. `.` = className.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub XMLhttpRequestTest()
    'Microsoft XML, v 6.0
    'Microsoft HTML object library

    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument, ohttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Const URL As String = "http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04BKW"
    Dim TRelements As Object, TRelement As Object

    With ohttp
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send

        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("#overviewQuickstatsDiv td.line.text")(4).innerText
        'Your other stuff
    End With
End Sub
```